# Help identify these protrusions on my leaky roof

Tags: leak, roof, patch

I've got a leaky roof on my 100-year old (new to me) Washington DC rowhouse.  I just finished clearing off a couple of years of decomposed leaf litter from the recessed spot where the leak is, and I'm about to start liberally slopping [wetpatch](http://us.henry.com/roofing/mastics-and-cements/208-wet-patch-roof-leak-repair/) over any and all inconsistencies in the roof that I can find.

The roof has these strange features:

[image]

What are they?

The copper-colored thing feels like old, brittle plastic.  Otherwise I have no idea what it is.

The one in the lower part of the frame is peeling up on one side.  It is a little bit flexible.  I could probably peel it off, but I don't know what I'd find underneath.  Likewise with the other.

If I knew what they were, then I might consider removing/replacing them before smearing the wetpatch all over them.  If I leave them, I have a lumpy surface to smear the sealant all over, and if I forget these things are there, I'll be creating surprises for myself/the roofer when I eventually need to replace the roof.

So what are these things and does it make sense to rip them off?

Comment: Broken paintbrush, stuck to a tin-can lid. Probably broke whilst attempting to swab sticky roofing goop, and since it was pouring rain at the time it just got left in place.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what that copper/brown colored thing is but the two round things look like the covers off of one gallon sized cans. My guess is that some previous owner was patching up a leak in that spot and there were a couple of holes in the roof.  They were using patch cement similar to what you are setting out to use and decided to stick down these can lids over the holes. Quite possibly the can lids came from their patch cement cans themselves.

If you can tell us a bit more about that copper colored thing it may be possible to clear up what that is as well. Maybe it was something placed on the lid to help hold it in place.

Comment: Not a bad theory.  I edited the post.  No idea what the copper-colored thing is, except that it seems like plastic, and is old and brittle.

Comment: That copper-colored thing looks like a piece broken off from the bottle that contained the elixir that fueled the idea of patching the roof holes with the cement can lids.